# I am getting error while loading my csv in spark using SQlcontext

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDNb2.png)

```
sparkDF = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('PR_DATA_35.csv')
```

> **ERROR_**
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 sparkDF = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')                                 .options(header='true').load('PR_DATA_35.csv')
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.pyc in load(self,
>   path, format, schema, **options)
>       157         self.options(**options)
>       158         if isinstance(path, basestring):
>   --> 159             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
>       160         elif path is not None:
>       161             if type(path) != list:
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1131         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1132         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1134     1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> /home/ec2-user/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       320             else:
>       321                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o312.load. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
>   in stage 5.0 (TID 23, 172.31.17.233, executor 0):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ec2-user/PR_DATA_35.csv
>   does not exist It is possible the underlying files have been updated.
>   You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH
>   TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame
>   involved.     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2853)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.infer(CSVDataSource.scala:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVDataSource.inferSchema(CSVDataSource.scala:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.inferSchema(CSVFileFormat.scala:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
>     at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:156)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ec2-user/PR_DATA_35.csv
>   does not exist It is possible the underlying files have been updated.
>   You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH
>   TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame
>   involved.     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It is a `FileNotFound` exception, is `'/home/ec2- user/PR_DATA_35.csv'` correct? There is an extra space in the path, is it a typo or?

Comment: No, it just got changed while editing on stack overflow.

Comment: Have you included the respective `jar` for `com.databricks.spark.csv` (even though that would throw a ClassNotFound Exception)? You said it works with pandas, I assume locally, where does the spark code run? Is it local also?

Comment: On ec2 it works with pandas as I have fetched data from s3 to my was instance using aws cli.

Comment: I did some research and problem is that you need to copy files across all clusters.

Comment: did you check which path is pandas using? I am guessing that pandas is reading from ec2 path but the spark code is trying to read from local.

Comment: You don't need to copy the files across all nodes, the file should just be somewhere accessible to all nodes. Also +1 for what @RameshMaharjan commented.

Comment: What spark version are you using? Spark version 2+ has built in read.csv function.

Comment: I am using Spark 2.3.

Comment: I was working on ec2 with 1 master instance and other slave instance. So, the path which I gave to pandas is master instance '/home/ec2-user'

Answer (score 1):

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ec2-user/PR_DATA_35.csv does not exist??

Comment: I cross checked by using pandas. Its working on pandas but not on spark.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not finding the file you want to convert to a DataFrame

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o312.load.: 
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times,
most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 23, 172.31.17.233,
executor 0): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ec2
user/PR_DATA_35.csv does not exist It is possible the underlying files
have been updated.
```

I have some recommendations

1. Verify the file is stored in your EC2 instance and It is in the same folder of your spark code.
2. Following the Databricks [guide](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-csv.html), You can specify the entire path to the file, for ec2 instances it should be something like: /home/ubuntu/project_folder/csv_file.csv
3. You can take a look to this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704333/spark-load-csv-file-as-dataframe?answertab=active#tab-top) question
4. This is the way I read csv files

   ```
   # submit to spark on my dev env
   # ./bin/spark-submit /Users/estebance/Documents/Projects/tests/spark_csv.py
   # Spark version 2.0 and up, spark-csv is part of core Spark functionality and doesn't require a separate library. So you could just do for example
   from pyspark import SparkContext
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
   spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("CsvReader").getOrCreate()
   csv_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/Users/estebance/Documents/Projects/tests/sample.csv")
   print(csv_df.head(2))
   ```

Hope this is helpful, best regards

Comment: 1. I have checked its on the same folder.      2. I did same to data bricks.         3. I tried builtin read csv file but error is same.

Comment: I have updated the answer with some code I've tested in my dev environment, I don't have a lot of knowledge about spark but in case you are still getting the error you should take a look to the installation

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what others have said, this error normally occurs in Spark when you are reading data from a folder, modifying it and saving on top of the data which you have initially read.

Just try saving the first set of data in a temporary folder or use the solution described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51590446/5595338).